# How to Disable to date based upon choosing from date

Tags: angularjs

I am using md-date picker in angular js ng-material.I want to show the To date based upon From date.(Eg.If am selecting Aug 27, 2018, in From date-column then I have to disable before 27aug 2018 in the To date picker.Here am disabling past date in From Date column using md-min-date="vm.minDate" For this vm.min date i write code in controller

```
<md-datepicker 
    ng-model="field.start_date" 
    md-min-date="vm.minDate" 
    md-placeholder="Date From"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>


<md-datepicker 
    ng-model="field.end_date" 
    md-placeholder="Date To"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

Please provide any solution for me.How to disable To date based upon choosing date in from date

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code, it's hard to know for sure, but based on the fragment above

```
<md-datepicker 
    ng-model="field.end_date" 
    md-min-date="field.start_date"
    md-placeholder="Date To">
</md-datepicker>
```